# My wordpress admin page shows white screen

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I was asked to change this site 
http://www.ellabar.com/ ,so i created a new test site as a sub domain of the main one as
http://test.ellabar.com/ 
Once the test site was done i was supposed to change the url to main one. I changed the url to main through general settings. Which i should not have done. Everything disappeared. I could not login to my wordpress login.

I searched a lot of topics to find a solution of changing urls in functions.php file of my theme folder. That worked but after sometime again it stopped working. Now someone suggested this to me on wordpress forum

**See:
You'll need to use FTP or Cpanel to change those back - the functions.php file method is pretty easy to do.
If the functions.php file is messed up, using FTP change the name on your active theme's folder - which will force WP to use a default theme (twentyfifteen). Then use the same functions.php file method to change the site URL's back in that twentyfifteen theme.**

Now this is what happens.
If i change the name of functions.php to anything else say wpfunctions.php than i can see the wordpress login page, correctly log into the dashboard and work in back end of wordpress but the website disappears. If i rename it to functions.php than website works correctly but wordpress login becomes a white screen. I want both the site and dashboard working. Can anyone help me with this please. I really need to make this site live in one day for my client.

Im using wordpress 4.0 and default theme is twenty fourteen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivating the current theme and re-installing it, fixed the white screen error.